# Create Python CLI with select interface

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-interface

I'd like to create a Python CLI with an item selection interface that allows users to choose an item from a list. Something like:

```
Select a fruit (up/down to select and enter to confirm):
[x] Apple
[ ] Banana
[ ] Orange
```

I'd like users to be able to change their selection using the up/down arrows and press `Enter` to confirm.

Does a Python module exist with this functionality? I tried searching but couldn't find exactly what I wanted.

The [select-shell Node.js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/select-shell) does exactly what I want.

The [pick Python module](https://github.com/wong2/pick) does what I want, but it uses curses and opens up a simple GUI. I would like to avoid creating a GUI and keep all output in the terminal: this likely requires updating lines displayed to the terminal.

I'm currently using [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) but I don't believe it supports this functionality. I'm not sure how exactly to implement this kind of feature using `cmd`/`readline` and would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found two libraries that met my needs!

The first is [python-inquirer](https://github.com/magmax/python-inquirer), a Python port of [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/), a CLI library used by projects like Yeoman. I found this library to have a really nice API (built on top of [blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/)) but lacks polish when it comes to design/features.

The second (which I will be using) is [whaaaaat](https://github.com/finklabs/whaaaaat), another Python port of Inquirer. This library offers functionality much closer to the original Inquirer.js and is exactly what I needed. The API is less clean than that of python-inquirer, however.

Examples:

`python-inquirer` example:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import inquirer

questions = [
    inquirer.List(
        "size",
        message="What size do you need?",
        choices=["Jumbo", "Large", "Standard", "Medium", "Small", "Micro"],
    ),
]

answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
pprint(answers)
```

`whaaaaat` example:

```py
from whaaaaat import prompt, print_json, Separator

questions = [
    {
        "type": "list",
        "name": "theme",
        "message": "What do you want to do?",
        "choices": [
            "Order a pizza",
            "Make a reservation",
            Separator(),
            "Ask for opening hours",
            {"name": "Contact support", "disabled": "Unavailable at this time"},
            "Talk to the receptionist",
        ],
    },
    {
        "type": "list",
        "name": "size",
        "message": "What size do you need?",
        "choices": ["Jumbo", "Large", "Standard", "Medium", "Small", "Micro"],
        "filter": lambda val: val.lower(),
    },
]

answers = prompt(questions)
print_json(answers)
```

Comment: Notes: (1) Windows support on python-inquirer is experimental
(2) Whaaaat is stale, with the developer stating in the readme that he does not have the time to work on the project.

Comment: I think python-inquirer is also using curses?

Answer (score 12):

Few more alternatives for command-line form input libraries:

- [tmbo/questionary](https://github.com/tmbo/questionary)
- [Exahilosys/survey](https://github.com/Exahilosys/survey)
- [kamik423/cutie](https://github.com/kamik423/cutie)
- [petereon/beaupy](https://github.com/petereon/beaupy)

Note: I am the maintainer of beaupy

Comment: +1 for making me go from "it's gonna be a hasle to find a Windows compatible option" to "oh..which one should I choose?"

Answer (score 8):

For simple choices you can use the [simple-term-menu](https://github.com/IngoHeimbach/simple-term-menu) package. It is simple, small and has no dependencies to other packages.

Example:

```py
from simple_term_menu import TerminalMenu

terminal_menu = TerminalMenu(["entry 1", "entry 2", "entry 3"])
choice_index = terminal_menu.show()
```

[image: simple-term-menu]

Comment: Attention: simple_term_menu does not work on windows. See https://github.com/IngoMeyer441/simple-term-menu#overview

Answer (score 0):

You mention the click package, and mention that you are not sure how to implement this feature. It seems like [choice-options](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#choice-options) are the intended way to implement single choice questions.

The generated output will not be nearly as nice as in some of the other packages mentioned in the other answers. However, click is well maintained, active, and works on both UNIX and WIN - critical arguments if you are planning to release a library.

Comment: The single choice might be a deal breaker for the OP, it's a fairly distinct user experience to an interactive multiple choice interface.

Comment: True: I'm not too familiar with choice-options, but yeah, it looks as if multiple-choice was not supported. However, I understood the OPs question ("Select a fruit") as explicitely targeting single-choice...

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'survey' module. Here you can type to filter the options or use up/down keys to navigate:

```
import survey  # pip install survey

colour_list = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink', 'silver', 'magenta']

index = survey.routines.select('Favorite colour? ',  options = colour_list,  focus_mark = '> ',  evade_color = survey.colors.basic('yellow'))
print(f'Answered {index}.')
```